# Django call function based on multiple events

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, celery, django-signals

In the Application, I need to call a function if there are any changes to few selected fields in five of the Models and few APIs gets called. What is the best approach to do this? I have considered doing it via signals but really appreciate best possible approaches and suggestions. Also, the function that needs to be called is fairly complex and if I'm converting it to background task, how can I make sure only latest call gets executed?

Comment: But why you want to execute a function on the change of code. Once the application is developed it has no use.

Comment: @RajatJain: I do not really see "change of code". Based on how I see he question, the OP means that certain *objects* are changed.

Comment: @RajatJain I didn't mean change of code, I need the function to be called when there is a change in values of fields of few Model entries or when few specific Django Views/APIs get called.